# Is there a way to generate XML-style comments for all methods/classes in project?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, comments, rider

When using an IDE like Visual Studio or Rider for C#, writing triple-slashes auto-completes to an XML-style comment, along with fields for input and output (when it comes to methods).

```
/// <summary>
/// This is an example!
/// </summary>
public static void ExampleMethod() { }
```

Is it possible to generate empty XML-style comments like this, but on an entire C# solution scope at once?

It doesn't seem like the aforementioned IDEs have the built-in capability to do that, and I've yet to find a plugin that completes this task.

Am I missing an existing solution, or is there no existing solution for this specific need of mine?

Any information would be helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: question: what would be the point? after all, you still have to edit each and every comment to add actually useful _content_.

Comment: I don't think it does the whole project but GhostDoc writes 90% of the comments you would write, automatically.

Comment: Is GhostDoc useful? [See the document.](https://submain.com/ghostdoc/GettingStarted/)

Answer (score 1):

I have solution for **Rider**:

1. Install this tool: https://github.com/p1va/dotnet-document
2. In Rider go to File > Settings > Tools | External Tools and add new external tool. Fields:
   Name:***DotnetDocument***
   Program:***dotnet***
   Arguments:***document apply $FilePath$***
   Working directory:***$ProjectFileDir$***
3. In Rider go to File > Settings > Keymap and in search field enter:DotnetDocument and add keyboard shortcut. For example: Ctrl + Shift + D
4. Enjoy

Comment: dotnet-document tool works well if you're comfortable with cli, or you can add it in External Tools in Visual Studio, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-external-tools?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution now.

1. Download This Extension from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KhaledMdTuhidulHossain.CXCommenter)  .
2. Install Extension.
3. Open Your Project in Visual Studio.
4. This tool can be accessed from the Visual Studio menu under "Edit > Generate Comment".

[image]